# Regex & ls or find

Tags: unix, find, ls

I need to select only directories between the periods of 2014**0729** - 2014**0921**.

The directories look like this.

20140729_154208  20140814_221350  20140829_215623

What is the best method to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`. It's almost invariably redundant and unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `find`

In order to find files modified within a range, **if the creation time of the last file in the directory matches the directory name**, the easiest way is to create files at the boundaries of the range and use the `-newer` predicate.

```
touch -t 201407290000 start
touch -t 201409210000 stop
find . -newer start \! -newer stop -type d
```

(I know not how to work with dates within `regex`, but I hope I have time to learn)

### Using `awk`

Yeah, why not using [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) instead of building a static `regex` to match the case?

Pass the find or ls result to `awk` with a little program checking the result is between `stop` and  `start` (NB: for  `find` I had to `substr(3,10)` for comparison):

```
find .  |awk -v start=20140729 -v stop=20140921 \
'{ curr=substr($0, 3, 10); if (curr <= stop && curr >= start) { print $0 } }'
```

(It worked for me on `AIX` and `Linux`)